# Laravel Image::make cannot find file on Windows server

Tags: laravel

On any linux server everything works fine, also on a WAMP installation. But somehow on a Windows 2012 Server with Apache and PHP 5.6.x I get with below code

```
$image = Image::make($request->file('image'))->encode('jpg');
```

The following error:

```
NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 18: Unable to find file ().
```

While when I print the array `$request->file('image')` I do see the original image with path `C:\Windows\Temp`

I am kinda lost in where to search for a solution for this issue, so any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Looks like a chmod issue with the `temp` folder. Try setting a 777 chmod on it.

Comment: That's also what I thought at first, but when I look in `C:\Windows\Temp` I do see the uploaded temp files

Comment: What do you mean by "when I look in..." ? Are you using a script? CLI? Windows explorer? Doesn't matter if you "see" files, PHP is the one who should "see" and access those files.

Comment: I am using explorer and see files like `php4053.tmp`, same as when I print the array of  `$request->file('image')`